# Getting a Canon Smartbase PC1230D to work under Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, printing, printer

I have an old Canon laser printer/copier that I want to use on a location where we only occasionally have to print something. Using this printer would be ideal, since it being a laser printer, the ink doesn't dry up, and since we have it, no need to buy a new printer. I was trying to set up a Raspberry Pi as a printer server, but it simply won't print.

I have installed CUPS on the rPi, and it sees the USB connection, but the printer type is not in the list of printers supported. I tried a few that were close in name, but none of those actually worked.

I tried downloading the Windows drivers I could find to see if there's a PPD, but couldn't locate that either.

Also tried installing the printer directly on my laptop, but unfortunately, neither on Win10 or Ubuntu, I can get a test page to work. Both see the device, but on Windows I can't get the drivers to install (they *are* labeled for Win2k or WinVista though) and on Ubuntu it installs as a Generic Text-Only Printer, but also there I can't get a test page to print.

The copier function is working fine.

Am I just out of luck, and have to buy a new printer, or is there some way to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have the same printer, and the only thing that worked for me is to install printer drivers in a "Windows XP **VM machine**" on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and passthrough the USB port to the printer, and it works fine